# How to set default value for textfield programmatically in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, entities

I need a form_alter code or something that I could use to set my field value. I'm getting the value from the parameter and I've tried a lot of ways but nothing works for me. This is the list of codes I've tried on my custom module:

```
function custommodule_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#node']->type == 'custom_package') {
      $default = $_GET['field_product_add_ons'];
      $form["field_add_on_nids"][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $default;
      $form['field_add_on_nids'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $default;
      $form['field_add_on_nids'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#default_value'] = $default;
      $form['field_add_on_nids'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#default_value'] = $default;

  }


  if($form_id == 'custom_package') {
      $default = $_GET['field_product_add_ons'];
      $form["field_add_on_nids"][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $default;
      $form['field_add_on_nids'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $default;
      $form['field_add_on_nids'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#default_value'] = $default;
      $form['field_add_on_nids'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#default_value'] = $default;

  }
}
```

I think the code will be simple but the field is still blank. My field is just a single text field.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your custom module called `custommodule_node` or just `custommodule`? Assuming it's `custommodule`, your function should look like below. You use `->` because node is an object.

```
function custommodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'custom_package') {
      $default = $_GET['field_product_add_ons'];
      $form->field_add_on_nids[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $default;
  }
}
```

also, there is no `if ($form['#node']->type == 'custom_package')`

Use `if ($form_id == 'custom_package')` to match $form_id.

Comment: Almost there, I removed what was unneeded. I also used dsm to double check everything. I found out that my form_id lacks "_node_form" at the end. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $form['field_add_on_nids']['und']['#default_value'] = $default;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try either of these way any one will work

**Option 1:**

```
$form['field_name']['und']['#default_value'][0] = $default_value;
```

**Option 2:**

```
$form['field_name']['und']['#default_value'] = $default_value;
```

**option 3 :**

```
$form['field_name']['und'][0]['value']['#default_value']= $default_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following, as it works for me:

```
$form['field_myfield'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#default_value'] = "value";
```

I believe that using LANGUAGE_NONE is considered a better practice than 'und'.